# PushSharp APNS Feedback Service Example

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp, pushsharp

We have implemented PushSharp for sending push notifications to our enterprise iOS devices.  This is being sent from a Windows machine and we customized the PushSharp code to be called from a console app which is scheduled to run every minute (checks SQL Server DB for push notifications to send and then sends what is returned).  This all works fine, but I have been unable to find an example of how to call the feedback service with this library.  I see there is a FeedbackService.cs class that looks to handle the connections with Apple's feedback service, but the documentation doesn't cover how it works or how you use it.

Does anyone have a good tutorial or an example of how to use the feedback service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code, looks like you don't use it directly.

You can register to the `Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired` of the PushService.

The event arguments will populate the parameter `deviceInfo` with the apple device id.